# Не работает тест для программы

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

```
import unittest
from 2048 import get_index


class Test_2048(unittest.Testcase):
    def test_1(self):
        self.assertEqual(get_index(1, 2), 7)
```

Comment: Переименуйте ваш модуль 2048 так, чтобы имя начиналось не с цифры, тогда его можно будет импортировать. Сейчас с точки зрения Python 2048 - это не имя модуля, а просто число.

Comment: спасибо большое